# How to use colors from theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I use the user defined colors created in the `theme`

```
export default createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: 'red',
      contrastText: '#ffffff'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: 'green',
      contrastText: '#ffffff'
    },
    error: {
      main: 'blue',
      contrastText: '#ffffff'
    }
  },
})
```

in a `React.Component`?

I am trying

```
import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
```

then

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
               <Avatar 
                   style={{backgroundColor: this.props.theme.primary}} />
            )
    }

const withThemeUserMenu = withTheme(Foo);
export default Foo;
```

That does not work. How do I access the colors from the theme?

Comment: You can try and console.log the props and see what you're working with. I'm not very familiar with material-ui but since the primary color is nested inside palette maybe it is this.props.theme.palette.primary? But I think if you console.log the props you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the way you are importing. If you are exporting an unamed export using `default` it doesn't matter what it's called and you don't need the braces.

They recommend doing it like this in their docs:

```
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

let theme = createMuiTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```